# Embedded Glassfish v3: deploying sun-resources.xml programmatically fails

Tags: jdbc, jakarta-ee, glassfish, java-ee-6, glassfish-embedded

I would like to be able to package my jpa-ejb-web project as a standalone application, by using Glassfish embedded API.

To use the JPA layer, I need to deploy the sun-resource.xml configuration, which should be possible with the [asadmin command](http://docs.sun.com/app/docs/doc/820-4497/add-resources-1?l=en&n=1&a=view) `add-resources path\to\sun-resources.xml`. I've this code to do it:

```
    String command = "add-resources";
    ParameterMap params = new ParameterMap();
    params.add("", "...\sun-resources.xml" );
    CommandRunner runner = server.getHabitat().getComponent(CommandRunner.class);
    ActionReport report = server.getHabitat().getComponent(ActionReport.class);
    runner.getCommandInvocation(command, report).parameters(params).execute();
```

but Glassfish refuses it with:

```
15-Jul-2010 16:34:12 org.glassfish.admin.cli.resources.AddResources execute
```

SEVERE: Something went wrong in add-resources

```
java.lang.Exception: ...\gfembed6930201441546233570tmp\lib\dtds\sun-resources_1_4.dtd (The system cannot find the path specified)
        at org.glassfish.admin.cli.resources.ResourcesXMLParser.initProperties(ResourcesXMLParser.java:163)
        at org.glassfish.admin.cli.resources.ResourcesXMLParser.<init>(ResourcesXMLParser.java:109)
        at org.glassfish.admin.cli.resources.ResourcesManager.createResources(ResourcesManager.java:67)
        at org.glassfish.admin.cli.resources.AddResources.execute(AddResources.java:106)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$1.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:305)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:320)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1176)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.access$900(CommandRunnerImpl.java:83)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1235)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1224)
        at javaapplication4.Main.main(Main.java:55)
```

and indeed, there is no `lib` directory on the indicated path ...

is there something wrong in my code? (I use [glassfish-embedded-all-3.0.1.jar](http://download.java.net/maven/glassfish/org/glassfish/extras/glassfish-embedded-all/3.0.1/))

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it by specifying an Embedded File System for the embedded Glassfish, and prepopulated the `/path/to/my/glassfish/lib/dtds` folder with the files which were missing.

```
        EmbeddedFileSystem.Builder efsb = new EmbeddedFileSystem.Builder();
        efsb.autoDelete(false);
        efsb.installRoot(new File("/path/to/my/glassfish"), true);

        EmbeddedFileSystem efs = efsb.build();
        Server.Builder builder = new Server.Builder("test");
        builder.embeddedFileSystem(efs);

        builder.logger(true);
        Server server = builder.build();
        server.addContainer(ContainerBuilder.Type.all);
        server.start();
```

and asking Glassfish not to delete the folder at the end of the execution.

Answer (score 1):

<strike>I'm not sure this is possible, [Running `asadmin` Commands Using the Sun GlassFish Embedded Server API](http://docs.sun.com/app/docs/doc/821-1208/gjldy?l=en&a=view) doesn't mention such a use case (passing a `sun-resources.xml`).</strike>

But I would use a preconfigured `domain.xml` instead of trying to deploy a `sun-resource.xml` file, the result should be similar. From the [Sun GlassFish Enterprise Server v3 Embedded Server Guide](http://docs.sun.com/app/docs/doc/821-1208/gjldt?a=view):

> #### Using an Existing `domain.xml` File
>
> Using an existing `domain.xml` file
>   avoids the need to configure embedded
>   Enterprise Server programmatically in
>   your application. Your application
>   obtains domain configuration data from
>   an existing `domain.xml` file. You can
>   create this file by using the
>   administrative interfaces of an
>   installation of nonembedded Enterprise
>   Server. To specify an existing
>   `domain.xml` file, invoke the
>   `installRoot`, `instanceRoot`, or
>   `configurationFile` method of the
>   `EmbeddedFileSystem.Builder` class or
>   a combination of these methods.

The documentation provides code samples showing how to do this (should be pretty straightforward).

Comment: I don't really agree with the first part of your answer, it's only two examples that they provide on the page! +1 however for suggesting the idea of preconfiguring the system

Comment: @Kevin: As I wrote, I'm not sure and I don't really use this API (I use a `domain.xml` that I bundle in my projects) so I might be wrong. Actually, now that I rethink about it, it should be indeed possible. Did you try to build an absolute path?